# Laplace transform of the function

Tags: functions

I just started studying Laplace transforms and I'm looking for some guidance on how to tackle this problem (I have the solution, just dont know the intermediate steps)

$$f(t)=t\cos(8t) + \mathrm e^{-2t}\sin(3t) + 2t^5 - 7\cos(4t)- 9.$$

Thanks

Comment: What approach are you using, tables or the formal definition?

Comment: Welcome to MSE! I'd recommend you this page http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference about how to format your question.

Comment: Not exactly sure on the aproach. Basically I'm studying an engineering subject that requires me to solve this problem and i have no idea how to start. The solution is given, but I am curious what steps I need to know to solve similar problems. I never studied Laplace.

Comment: I would strongly suggest reading the first half and going through the examples: http://faculty.uml.edu/Dimitris_Christodoulou/Teaching/documents/laplace.pdf, otherwise, you will be lost and make this much harder on yourself. Also, here is a nice table: http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/DE/Laplace_Table.aspx

Comment: Thank you. I found the tables a nice resource to have :)